# Performance testing: JMeter vs Tsung

Tags: jmeter, tsung

What's the differences between JMeter and Tsung? I read that Tsung may generate more load than JMeter if test with same hardware, but how close it to reality?

Answer (score 7):

Tsung is written in Erlang and said to be capable of running an extreme number of simultaneous users (10000+)

Jmeter is written in Java and quite capable of generating large amounts of load, assuming your test plan is good.

Here are some limitations in regards to performance in JMeter

- Every user in Jmeter is an OS thread. This increases overhead when using a lot of concurrent users (jmeter best practices recommends using a low number of threads, http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html - in my experience you may run into problems when using more than 1000 threads per jmeter instance, but that may vary a lot depending on your test plan). You will also need to tweak JVM settings when running larger tests.
- You can easily destroy performance & run out of PermGen memory if you have dynamic scripts (scripts that have to be recompiled every time because of jmeter variable expansion). Put your scripts in separate files or use a compilation cache key to avoid recompilation.
- Using some test components (such as the Tree View, which keeps every request & response in memory) can wreak havoc on your load generator

I've tested some VERY large sites with JMeter, and as long as you are able to reduce the number of threads (reducing user-waits to keep throughput at your desired level) Jmeter is fine. There is quite a large community around JMeter, plugins for load testing using a lot of protocols & monitoring various systems. JMeter has also good scripting support - java, javascript, whatever that can be loaded in to a jvm basically (including for example groovy), so it is very extensible.

At one time (using jmeter 2.6 I think) I ran some 30,000 database requests per second (Oracle JDBC) from a single load generator, and there have been some optimizations since, so as long as you dont have extreme requirements, Jmeter is fine. Pick the one that suits your needs and your experience.

Note: I have very little experience using Tsung.

Edit: Nowadays I use Locust (https://github.com/locustio/locust/). Tsung has not been updated since 2017, and Locust's user/threading model (greenlets) supports more concurrent users than Jmeter. But most importantly it has a more flexible workflow (actual Python code instead of configuration/clicking in a GUI)

Answer (score 3):

It's always depends on your scenario and amount off datas used for variablility, the ratio is closed to ten, when you'll be able to run 100 user/second with JMeter, Tsung will be easy with 1000 user/sec.